# Updating boolean values in the database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a new row in my wp_users table in the database

[image]
This new row will store a boolean value, but for some reason I am unable to update the value in the database on form submission. Here's how I have attempted to do this;

```
<?php
    global $current_user;
    global $wpdb;
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;

    // event submission form
    if( isset( $_POST['final_submit'] ) ){

        $wpdb->update('wp_users', array(
            'events_submitted'  =>  1
        ), array('ID' => $user_id));

        echo 'submitted';
    }
?>
```

After turning on debug mode I am getting this error;

```
WordPress database error: [Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction]
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? (I see no SQL there.)

Comment: @jarlh is the update command not sql? sorry I'm quite new to this

Comment: No, that's not SQL. In SQL you'd do something like `UPDATE wp_users SET col = 'value'`.

Comment: @jarlh ok I'll remove it thanks

Comment: No problem! Perhaps you should add <wordpress> or <wpdb> instead?

Comment: $wpdb->update('wp_users', array(
            'events_submitted'  =>  1
        ), array('ID' => $user_id)); This will also work. Have a look at this : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/

Comment: Why do you need a whole custom row? User meta is just one line of code and much more convenient and accessible https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/

Comment: @Artem Its just how the current database is already set, so just working with what I've been given